# sending a split message using TCP Protocol

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the Client to get a String, cut it in half, send it to Server, concatenate it backwards, then return it to Client.
The Client then checks whether the returning string is indeed the concatenated s2+s1.

Struggling as I can't find a way for the server to receive the split message and not a "whole". so I have to repeat the splitting process twice, once in client and once in server.

I don't want to use Delimiter with Split on the Server side.
is there really no way of receiving 2 messages?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

The server will receive whatever you write to the socket. TCP is a *transport* protocol, so there is no concept of individual "requests". Your current approach of using a delimiter (`\n`) that the server uses to distinguish the two parts, is a perfectly acceptable solution. You'll always need to perform the split on the client side in order to verify that the server's response is correct.

If you want to avoid the call to `split` in the Server: instead of using fixed-size buffers in the Client and Server, your client could first send two integers indicating the lengths of the two parts (use an integer type of a known size, like 32 bits). Your server could then read both integers and allocate a buffer of the appropriate size. Then, it would copy each byte received into the second half of the buffer until it has copied the number of bytes in the first part (indicated by the first integer received). Then, it just needs to copy the remainder of the request into the first half of the buffer.

In this approach, your client will start by just sending the string to the server. Upon receiving a response, it will have to compare it with the input string and verify that the server's response is correct.